# MS Project assigning one resources to multiple task

Tags: ms-project

I need help assigning my Project Lead to a report writing task on a specific day. However, the Project Lead is also assigned to a system testing task that runs for a longer period and has multiple resources assigned to it. When I try to allocate the Project Lead to both tasks at 50%, my finish dates get pushed out. Can you please assist me with this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My PL is scheduled from June 01 to August 31 for testing during this time the PL lead needs to write a monthly status report which take approximately 6 hours to write/edit/approve for submission to the project sponsor.  I need to allocate the PL for the test and the report on the days it is due.  I want to assign both to the PL but not change durations because of a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the report writing task is at the end of the system testing task. Given that scenario, the Gantt Chart would look something like this

[image]

Since the PL can't do his/her part of the system testing simultaneously with the report writing, assign the PL at 100% to both tasks. In this example I created a team of 4 resources working in conjunction with the PL for the system testing. The Task Usage view looks like this:
[image]